# how to get all the data where specific string included in c#, mvc

Tags: c#, json, string, where-clause

I'm filtering data from converted json file like below.

```
var allResult = ItineraryD.Where(d => d.departurePort == departuredate);
```

but this should have date like this `04/03/16`, but I want to get all the data if it includes only this part `03/16`(that means data which includes `03/16` string inside `departuredate`).how can I do that.

Comment: I strongly recommend parsing your dates and working with *real* DateTimes and TimeSpans.

Comment: try this:     
`var allResult = ItineraryD.Where(d => d.departurePort.Contains(departuredate));`